# Display: table, display: table-cell на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: css3

Caniuse сказал, что на сегодняшний день display: table, display: table-cell поддерживаются хорошо. Для уверенности хочу понять, можно ли без проблем использовать его на мобильных устройствах — задавать нужные ширину, высоту, отступы, вкладывать дивы, спаны и прочее; будет ли display: table послушным именно на мобильных устройствах?

P.s. Про flex знаю, просто хочу хорошо понять работу именно display: table.

Comment: display: table является более старый чем flex, т.е. поддерживается большим количеством браузеров, а точнее более старыми версиями

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что выдаёт [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table). Решайте сами.